# UITableView's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a`UIViewController` with a`UITableView` in it. The tableview has customized cells, with textfields inside it. The delegates of the textfield are set to that class.

On edit of a textfield(`textFieldDidBeginEditing`) I have a drop down(`UIView`with a tableview in it). The dropdown is created programmatically.
The problem I am facing is, the`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of the dropdown tableview isn't being called. I have set the delegate, datasource to the class rightly. I have removed all other gestures too. I have made sure that the tableview isn't in editing mode.

On the clicks of cells in the dropdown, the only thing that works is my background tableview's textfield's delegate methods.

```
//UITableView class(with textfield from where dropdown is loaded.)
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

if(textField.tag == 3){
    if(dropDown == nil) {
        CGFloat f = 200;
        dropDown = [[SFTextFieldDropDown alloc] showDropDownWithSender:textField withHeight:f andElements:self.list];
        dropDown.delegate = self;
        }
    }
}

// Custom Drop down class.
- (id)showDropDownWithSender:(UITextField *)senderTextField withHeight:(CGFloat)height andElements:(NSArray *)array{

    table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, btn.size.width, 0)];
    table.delegate = self;
    table.dataSource = self;
    table.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    table.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.239 green:0.239 blue:0.239 alpha:1];
    table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    table.separatorColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [table setAllowsSelection:YES];
    table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, btn.size.width, *height);
    [table setEditing:NO];
    [self addSubview:table];
}
return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 40;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.list count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
}
if([list count] > 0)
    cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code here for a better review

Comment: Have you added any gesture to your view ??

Comment: No. The superview had gestures, but I removed that too.

Comment: Have you implemented the correct method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` not `didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: Checked that too. Its correct.

Comment: Where are you placing Tableview? And are you able to scroll the tableview? And are you able to see the selection change when clicking the tableview. For more thorough answers, please place your code here.

Comment: In which class have you implemented the delegate methods?

Comment: are you sure that the delegates you are setting on SFTextFieldDropDown is being passed on to the tableview delegate ?

Comment: Its a a small tableview, so doesnt scroll obviously

Comment: @JennyJose SFTextfieldDropDown is my dropdown view class. The delegate are set rightly.

Comment: btw are you writing the table.dataSource and table.delegate implementation i.e didSelectRow in SFTextfieldDropDown ?

Comment: Yes, I am. Delegates are set and methods implemented. Datasource methods in Dropdown class are working fine.

Comment: First of all, it's a very bad idea to handle multiple tableview's by the same view controller. I strongly suggest you to create a class (inherited from UIView), make tableview there and set delegate and datasource to that class and implement tableview's methods in that class. Then, in `showDropDownWithSender` just create an instance of that newly created view and add as subview.

Comment: The tableview with the textfield cell is in a UIViewController. On the click of the textfield(textfield edit), that I am loading my dropdown. The dropdown is a UIView which has table view added as its subview. So no view has to handle multiple tableview delegates in this case.

Comment: Just a thought about design. Could your drop-down tableview be replaced by a pickerview? I use pickerviews as the inputview for text fields in a table, works fine.

Comment: Can you push your project to GitHub?

Comment: Seeing the comments, there is still an obvious lack of code to help you out. I'll still take my shot at helping you by suggesting you add an uibutton in your dropdown view and see if its touch release inside is triggered. While not reaching understanding of the issue, if this works then you could user buttons in your dropdown cells otherwise the problem will be simpler to detect and solve with the UIButton than the table.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see you're not populating your tableview, it's as simple as that.

If you're not giving it an array and not calling -`reloadData`, then it'll never call the delegate methods. (`numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`)

Comment: I am populating the tableview. cellForRowAtIndexPath and other datasource methods are working just fine in the Dropdown class. Its the click events that aren't working.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, you are not setting `self.list` to the array you receive in

```
- (id)showDropDownWithSender:(UITextField *)senderTextField 
                  withHeight:(CGFloat *)height 
                 andElements:(NSArray *)array
```

Add `self.list = array` and that should fix it

Comment: I am doing it. Just that I didn't post that part of the code. The tableview is rightly populated with the list.

Answer (score 2):

So with your question explanation, you have totally two `UITableView` in your ViewController's view & multiple `UITextFields` ( like textField which invokes the dropDown & the dropdown itself has textfields in each row.)

So the problem is, the `UITableView delegate` is set to the `self` ( that means two `UITableView` are delegating to one class. So upon receiving `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate which `tableview` should be considered to respond back. For this you have to add tags to the `TableView`, like

`#define MAIN_TABLE_VIEW 1001`

`#define DROP_DOWN_TABLE_VIEW 1002`

Now in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, try to re-direct your path of execution to the right tableView based on tag values.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(tablview.tag == MAIN_TABLE_VIEW){
    // follow your code for main table view here
    }

    if(tablview.tag == DROP_DOWN_TABLE_VIEW){
     // follow your code for dropdown table view here.
    }
}
```

The same approach you may have to follow in all `delegates` & 1`datasource` of `UITableView`.

Hope this solves the purpose.

Comment: No. The Dropdown tableview delegates, I am handling another class.

Comment: Then please use `sender.bounds` instead of `0` while setting the `Dropdown UITableView` frame. Like `sender.bounds.origin.x, sender.bounds.origin,y, width, height`

Answer (score 2):

i think i had the same problem, where have you declared the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`, just in ViewController only?

I think you have lost the delegate, because you need and did assigned the delegate to the `TableView` inside the `UIView`? Right?

**Reassign the delegates** upon showing or calling/loading tableview from another view..

Hope this is useful.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish something very similar to what you are trying to do for a past project. What we ended up doing was using the `textfield.inputView` instead to contain the `tableView` like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your touches are received by `UITextField` and not being passed to the below cell. What you have to do is set `textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO` initially so that touches are received by cell.

And then do this :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // get the reference to the text field
    textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Still the textfield delegate captures the click.

Comment: Bad, bad answer

Comment: It will work only once, need to reload tableview for setting its original state.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear which view you're adding your dropdown subview in. Are you adding it in the tableView or in the view that contains the tableView (btw, by your description, you ARE NOT using a UITableViewController). My guess is that you're adding it in the tableview and that is causing problems. Try adding it to the overall ViewController.view (which means you will have to get the proper co-ordinates of the frame relative to the textField within the cell).